# Left join table on first word from old table?

Tags: mysql, left-join

How do you left join table on first word from other table?

this returns titles from new table but old table is null where I know that first words in titles are full match

```
SELECT tb1.title as new_titles,tb2.title as old_title
FROM tb1.news_items
LEFT JOIN
tb2.news_items 
ON
tb1.title = SUBSTRING_INDEX(tb2.title, '', 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the first word from the title on the second table

```
CASE CHARINDEX(' ', tb2.title, 1)
WHEN 0 THEN tb2.title
ELSE SUBSTRING(tb2.title, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', tb2.title, 1) - 1)
END
AS FirstWord
```

So the query will be like

```
SELECT tb1.title as new_titles,tb2.title as old_title
    CASE CHARINDEX(' ', tb2.title, 1)
    WHEN 0 THEN tb2.title
    ELSE SUBSTRING(tb2.title, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', tb2.title, 1) - 1)
    END
AS FirstWord
FROM tb1.news_items
LEFT JOIN
tb2.news_items 
ON
tb1.title = FirstWord
```

Comment: i have not tested this yet as i do not have sql server on my computer i am using but it should be correct